# InvalidOperationException When Appending Text To RichTextBox

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im trying to append text to richtextbox when there is a progress changed in BackgroundWorker thread.

**DoWork event**

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1000];
        client.Client.Receive(buff);
        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff);
        background.ReportProgress(0, s);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

**ProgressChanged Event**

```
try
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(e.UserState as string);
}
catch { }
```

i dont understand what is the problem... it worked fine and suddenly its not.

Comment: might be a cross thread issue. include the exception in the question to provide more details of the problem

Comment: If e.UserState is not of type string, e.UserState as string will provide null. Maybe is problem with that.

Comment: Is the thread allowed to modify the richtextbox?

Comment: Read up on `Control.Invoke` and `Control.InvokeRequired`. It's very likely a cross-thread issue. Remember that the Form is a control, so you can just create a `AppendTextToRichTextControl` that uses `this.InvokeRequired` to decide whether the AppendText... method should be Invoked.

Comment: Don’t swallow general exceptions